# How to express the phrase "to look absentmindedly" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm not a native speaker and I need some help. I'm brushing up my English doing some exercises. One of them wants me to translate the phrase "to look absentmindedly" using just one verb. Could you, please, give me a hand?

Comment: I assume you mean to *look **at** [something] absent-mindedly*, not to *appear to be absent-minded*. In which case probably you just want **glance**, but we don't normally do "translations" here.

Comment: Oh, yes, I've forgotten to use "at". Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Not everything has to be a single word.  You can take a gander at http://thesaurus.com/browse/glance  though.

Comment: This question is in jeopardy of being closed because it is incomplete: lacks research. It can be improved by adding the results of your research.

Answer (score 1):

Without context it's hard to narrow down, but here's a few random ideas:

- overlook: to look without seeing or perceiving
- gawk: to stare or gape stupidly
- gongoozle: to observe idly (not widely known)
- muse: to gaze meditatively (implies that the looker's eyes are open, but their thoughts are elsewhere)
- wander: to look idly from one place to another
- range: to glance over a series of objects or look over an area

Answer (score -1):

My best recommendation would be "gaze", as I think this gives the impression of staring absentmindedly, although adding "absentmindedly" would obviously strengthen the meaning of any verb we could suggest.  I don't think there is any single verb that conveys that same meaning.

Other common expressions are "stare off into space" or "stare off into the distance".

Comment: **Gaze** is appropriate if the person is staring at one thing (for some time) without really seeing it - compare [**thousand-yard stare**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand-yard_stare).  However, if I understood the OP's question correctly, the situation he has in mind is, e.g., standing at the door while looking around the room, patting your pockets, and trying to remember what you meant to take with you.  (I find myself doing this *all the time*.)  In that case, the word is (as @FumbleFingers pointed out) **glance**.

Comment: I just realized I made an unwarranted gender assumption when I said "the situation **he** has in mind".  Извините, Ксения!

Comment: @sacohe, "I don't think there is any single verb..." is an unsupported opinion.  Can you include the resources you've consulted?

Comment: This is my opinion, which is why I prefaced my claim with "I don't think". Can you think of a single word that means what the OP is asking? I was unable to think of or find a better synonym than the one I suggested. I do think that for any context the poster may be using such a verb could be greatly strengthened with "absentmindedly".

Comment: Normally, I'd think of a _gaze_ as being the _opposite_ of an absent-minded look. A gaze is a long and steady stare, at least according to [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gaze). That said, the [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/gaze#gaze_4) definition acknowledges _two_ forms of gazing – one absent-minded, the other much more intent and focused.

Comment: Ничего страшного!